# fullcalendar version 4 css issue

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar version 4.  I have two renders of fullcalendar for an application I'm building.   The mini calendar to the left of the main calendar has a bit of a css problem.  When I click on the link if there are 'more events' to show than what can be displayed in the tiny calendar block, the popover that opens does not seem to show over the main calendar's time slots.

Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about.

I tried to add a zindex css property of 999999 (as a start) to class = fc-popover fc-more-popover, but nothing seem to make the popover box to appear over the timegrid lines and time details in the calendar next to it.

[image: ca]

Comment: Have you tried !important with z-index, like z-index: 999999 !important ?

Comment: You may check timegrid calendar z-index, it might be more than the value you gave, than you might need to give more value to z-index for popover.

Comment: I have tried that, yes.  To me it seems like the element with class = fc-view-container (the right calendar) won't allow me to cover element with class = fc-popover fc-more-popover   I'm trying to add a higher z-index with !important to the popover and also trying to add a lower z-index to the timegrid.  

I'm still working on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I add this css and it seems to work!

```
#calendar_mini .fc-view {
    z-index: auto
}
```

The main calendar and the mini one both has z-index = 0, and adding this css worked.